# SwiftUI Animation Broken After Resuming App

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui

I have a very simple, sequenced progress animation.  When the app loads, it works perfectly.  However, if I switch apps or go to the Home Screen then go back to my app, the sequencing is broken.

Here is the relevant code:

```
@State private var progressOpacity: CGFloat = 0.0

...

HStack(spacing: 3.0) {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
                        .opacity(progressOpacity)
                        .animation(
                            Animation.easeIn(duration: 1.0)
                                .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
                                .delay(0.0),value: self.progressOpacity
                        )
                        
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
                        .opacity(progressOpacity)
                        .animation(
                            Animation.easeIn(duration: 1.0)
                                .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
                                .delay(0.33),value: self.progressOpacity
                        )
                        
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
                        .opacity(progressOpacity)
                        .animation(
                            Animation.easeIn(duration: 1.0)
                                .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
                                .delay(0.66),value:  self.progressOpacity
                        )
                }
                .onAppear {
                    self.progressOpacity = 1.0
                }
```

I have tried multiple alternatives, including a boolean "animationEnabled" value to toggle the animation via onChange and nothing seems to work.  I realize that a timer-based alternative (rather than an animation), where I alter the dot opacity at regular intervals could work.  But this is a small subset of a larger animation.  A timer-based approach doesn't work for some of the other elements.

Comment: Have you tried listening to the background/active state of the app and resetting based on that?

Comment: Good suggestion, and I've tried the following if this is what you had in mind:  Under .onAppear I added .onChange and "turned off" the animation when the phase became .background.  Didn't seem to help.

Comment: I suspect you need a [pausable animation](https://swiftuirecipes.com/blog/pause-and-resume-animation-in-swiftui). That way, when the app moves to the background, you can pause it, and when it comes to the foreground you can continue the animation. A regular animation does not handle this sort of transition at all, as you are finding.